# How to make struts bean:message to return key itself in case of the translation not found?

Tags: struts, translation, jsp-tags

I am using struts bean:message for translation.

```
<bean:message key="somekey"/>
```

If I have value in the translation_en.properties for somekey, I am getting the response properly. In my requirement I may also have keys that may not have the translations and in such case, I need the "somekey" to be displayed. But, struts is returning "???en.somekey???" when the value is not found in properties.

Answer (score 1):

I guess not possible yet. Unless you request a change to the struts team.

But it's possible that you tailor your own tag by mimicking what `<bean:message>` do and change the logic just a little bit.

Also as a workaround. You can just define in the properties key=key.

Comment: The key is dynamic, so cannot add it to properties.

Comment: If you want it a dynamic solution. you have to tailor a self-defined tag yourself. Like http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/JSPTags.html

Comment: Is there a work around from the UI to check if it starts with "???" and replace it?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea. It will make your code a mess. Simply tailor your own tag. And modify the logic of adding "???" will be much better. You can even add a default value if you need. Much flexible indeed.